# Socket.io stopped working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, socket.io

I don't know what possibly could have change, but my client/server communication with socket.io stopped working.
Here is my server app :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
   socket.on('disconnect', function(){ 
     console.log('user disconnected'); 
  });        
});

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        io.sockets.emit("message",message);
});
```

The message are printed in the console. The "consumer" is a Kafka consumer but this shouldn't matter.
Here is my client component:

```
this.connection = this.streamService.getMessages().subscribe((message: string) => { 
        console.log("Receiving message " + message);
}
```

Here is my client service:

```
getMessages() { 

    let observable = new Observable(observer => { 
        this.socket = io.connect(this.url);

        this.socket.on('message', (data: any) => {
             console.log(data);
             observer.next(data.value); 
        }); 
        return () => {
             this.socket.disconnect(); 
        }; 
    }) 
    return observable; 
}
```

None of my client side log are displayed except "user connected". I get a Get request to http:/localhost:3000/socket.io/ frequently. Both client and server use "socket.io-client": "^2.0.1".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Change it to `io.sockets.on('connection', (consumer) => {` and it will work

Comment: Actually "consumer" is a totally different variable that I am listening on. When "consumer" gets a message I want to send it via socket

Comment: now it's clear :) try to use 'io.sockets.emit("<some other event name>", message);` as "message" is a reserved event name

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem... I get a "GET 
http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/199/bhmrmlil/websocket [HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols 2ms]" in firefox console.